# Name issue. Can't change the name of the Models in django database

Tags: python, django

from django.db import models

```
# Create your models here.
class Course  (models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  language= models.CharField(max_length=100)
  price= models.CharField(max_length=100)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

in django database the object dosent change name still named Course object (1) in the list. Why does it not change? def **str**(self):
return self.name
what should one do to make django show the courses names? This should be correct. no errors or anything it just simply dosent do what it should. it seems strange.

Comment: Do you mean django admin ? And have you tried reloading your dev server ?

Comment: Yes, the admin, and yes have reloaded it, it dosent change. weird.

Comment: Your ```__str__``` method indentation is wrong..

Answer (score 1):

The `__str__` function should be in your class, not after it

```
class Course(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    language = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class Course(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    language= models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price= models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Answer (score 0):

i got answer for this so you have to add this in respective modules like i have category module in which models.py and then add this method.

Comment: please provide specific answer to the given question.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).